# How to scale Prometheus using Rancher Monitoring?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, rancher

I'm using rancher and the monitoring plugin that installs prometheus. As the cluster grows, prometheus is using more and more CPU and memory to scrape and query data to the point it's the most consuming pod in the cluster.

I noticed the UI shows "prometheis" plural and the workload is a statefulset, but as I understand prometheus doesn't work as a cluster. Can I just scale the set to more pods? What happens? how does it work?

I can't find any information on the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't scale Prometheus by adding more pods; one approach (most common) is to set up [federation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/) to scale it up.